# how to start new lifeline in sequence diagram at higher levels using PlantUML

Tags: uml, graphviz, sequence-diagram, plantuml

**BACKGROUND**

In order to show ongoing operations of "activities" or "messages" within actors, lifelines can be used. PlantUML's sequence diagrams provide a mechanism to stack these lifelines for each actor and even colorize them.

**MY APPLICATION**

Within my sequence diagram I try to represent active calculations within actors by drawing lifelines. And even show a representation of "indentation levels" according to the inner code structure where the activity / message stems from. Now, when I jump between actors, I want to activate, deactivate and re-activate lifelines within the respective actors.

The principle is shown by the following PlantUML sequence:

```
@startuml

'
' 1
'
activate "actor 1" #Olive
"actor 1" -> "actor 1": actor1 activity1
activate "actor 1" #OliveDrab
"actor 1" -> "actor 1": actor1 sub-activity1
deactivate "actor 1"
"actor 1" -> "actor 1": actor1 activity2\nactor1 summary1
activate "actor 1" #OliveDrab
"actor 1" -> "actor 1": actor1 sub-activity2\nactor1 sub-activity3
"actor 1" -> "actor 5" : 
deactivate "actor 1"
deactivate "actor 1"
activate "actor 5" #Olive
"actor 5" -> "actor 5": general func activity1\ngeneral func activity2
activate "actor 5" #OliveDrab
"actor 5" -> "actor 5": general func sub-activity1
"actor 5" -> "actor 1" : 
deactivate "actor 5"
deactivate "actor 5"

'
' 2
'
activate "actor 1" #Olive
activate "actor 1" #OliveDrab
"actor 1" -> "actor 1": actor1 sub-summary1
"actor 1" -> "actor1_func1()" : 
deactivate "actor 1"
deactivate "actor 1"
activate "actor1_func1()" #Olive
"actor1_func1()" -> "actor1_func1()": actor1 func1 activity1\nactor1 func1 activity2
"actor1_func1()" -> "actor2_func1()" : 
deactivate "actor1_func1()"
activate "actor2_func1()" #Olive
"actor2_func1()" -> "actor2_func1()": actor2 func1 activity1
"actor2_func1()" -> "actor 1" : 
deactivate "actor2_func1()"

'
' 3
'
activate "actor 1" #Olive
activate "actor 1" #OliveDrab
activate "actor 1" #MediumSeaGreen
"actor 1" -> "actor 1": actor1 sub-sub-activity1
deactivate "actor 1"
"actor 1" -> "actor 1": actor1 sub-activity4
deactivate "actor 1"
"actor 1" -> "actor 1": actor1 activity3
@enduml
```

The following image shows the result:

[image: the resulting diagram from the PlantUML text sequence above]

**MY PROBLEM**

Looking at the diagram above, you see three markers. The 1st marker `(1)` shows how it was intended to look like: the first lifeline is created below action1 and then overlayed by another, short lifeline, which is then deactivated and re-activated again. Then the sequence walks over to actor5... The 2nd marker `(2)` shows that when returning from actor5 back to actor1 the double "activate actor1" from the text sequence results in only *one* visible lifeline, placed right of the middle line. The 3rd marker `(3)` now shows the same as seen before, just with three subsequent "activate actor1" text rows. It can be seen, that all lifelines are displayed even more on the right of the middle line and all directly above each other.

I would like to be able to create lifelines visibly stacked as seen in (1) even when I create three "activations" in subsequent text rows. For me, this looks like a bug, although I guess there are not many people trying something like this. But for me this would be important: to be able to re-activate lifelines at higher levels without loosing the stacked view.

Any hints?

Comment: not sure to understand you, do you want something like [sd without explicit return](https://www.bouml.fr/sd.png) or [sd with explicit return](https://www.bouml.fr/sdr.png) ?

Comment: or may be [other sd without explicit return](https://www.bouml.fr/sd2.png) or [other sd with explicit return](https://www.bouml.fr/sd2r.png) ?

Comment: thanks for your reply, @bruno, I think, the [staggered lifelines without return](https://www.bouml.fr/sd.png) are the closest to what I want to create. But in my case, I want the lifelines to **break down completely**, as soon as operation shifts to another actor. This is already done in my example above. The problem lies in the re-activation of actors: when returning to a previously abandoned actor, I want the lifelines to **start at the level at which the actor has been left off** beforehand. plz see the [markers](https://www2.pic-upload.de/img/36737592/diagram_showing_critical_entries.jpg)

Comment: "*when returning to a previously abandoned actor, I want the lifelines to start at the level at which the actor has been left off beforehand*" : you cannot ask for that, when a message is received it is in a new ExecutionSpecification (like in the execution stack when your program runs) visible when using overlapping notation. As you can see in my second couple of diagrams even they are not shift to the right the new ExecutionSpecifications are *on* the others. Note I suppose you are using *synchronous* messages, of course if you are using asynchronous message this is different.

Comment: maybe it is rather understandable when we don't talk about "messages" but of "tokens". I'd like to pass a token from one level of execution within one actor to anorher actor. And when returning the token to the first actor, the operation resumes exactly at the same level as the token was first sent from.

Comment: Whatever the message is, while it is synchronous the sender has to wait for the end of the execution/management done on the receiver side, else use an asynchronous message (seems to be `->>` on PlantUML, even very sadly PlantUML does not reuse UML terminology on its documentation not UML rules for the message arrow head drawing)